# Accessing native C++ data from managed C++

Tags: c++, native, managed

I have an native C++ library which makes use of a large static buffer (it acquires data from a device).

Let's say this buffer is defined like this:

```
unsigned char LargeBuffer[1000000];
```

Now I would like to expose parts of this buffer to managed C++, e.g. when 1000 bytes of new data are stored by the library at `LargeBuffer[5000]` I would like to perform a callback into managed C++ code, passing a pointer to `LargeBuffer[5000]` so that managed C++ can access the 1000 bytes of data there (directly if possibile, i.e. without copying data, to achieve maximum performance).

What is the best way to let managed C++ code access data in this native array?

Comment: It's spelled "native" not "unmanaged"

Comment: Aren't they synonyms, in this context?

Comment: "unmanaged" comes off as slightly pompous to native programmers

Comment: I don't want to be "pompous" so I changed "unmanaged" to "native" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed C++ can access the unmanaged memory just fine.  You can just pass in the pointer and use it in managed c++.

Now, if you want to then pass that data into other .NET languages, you'll need to copy that data over to managed memory structures or use unsafe code in C#

Comment: Actually I'll have to pass back the data from managed C++ to C# so I guess I'll have to use unsafe code.

Comment: CLI C++ and C# mix perfectly fine, there is no need for the unsafe keyword.

Comment: @high6: There is if he wants to access the raw pointer from C#.

Answer (score 1):

As of .net 2.0 and the new IJW you should be able to access the buffer directly from CLI C++.

As long as you dont specify "#pragma unmanaged" then the code will be compiled as a form of managed which is what allows the direct access.

Comment: Ok from C++, but if I want to access the raw pointer from C# too, I'll have to use unsafe keyword. Thanks for pointing me to IJW: I know very little about the managed-unmanaged mechanisms, now I'm understanding a bit more.